# Debug error "no source available for main()" with SDL project

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdb, mingw, sdl

I got troubles while debugging a C++ project using SDL 1.2.15, instead my program runs correctly without any sort of problem. In fact launching debug, error "No source avalailable for main() at [hexadecimal address] appears and the only thing I can do in Eclipse is click on "View Disassembly", that show me all assembler istructions performed, veryfing that in fact the address specified in the error, is not that of main(), but the immediately previous.

```
include "SDL/SDL.h"
int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
SDL_Surface* screen;
SDL_Surface* sur;
screen=SDL_SetVideoMode(1280,720,32,SDL_SWSURFACE);

//Start SDL
SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
sur=SDL_LoadBMP("immagine.bmp");
SDL_BlitSurface(sur,NULL,screen,NULL);
SDL_Flip(screen);
SDL_Delay(4000);
//Quit SDL
SDL_Quit();
return 0;
}
```

The program is very simple, so I don't think the issue is related with the contents of code and it seems even not related with gdb because of it works fine with C++ projects, but the problem appears only using SDL.
I tried to change default compiler tags from -g3 to -g, but nothing changed. 
I'm working on Eclipse Mars.2 on Windows 10 (64 bit) using MinGW gcc and gdb. 
Maybe the problem is related to uncorrect linking of debug libreries in MinGW?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was on the entry point of Debugger, in fact SDL defines his own main(SDL_main), so I solved the problem changing from "Debug Configuration"menu, Debugger label, the field "Stop on startup at" from default value "main" in "SDL_main".